# Using free() corrupts char array data in C

Tags: c, free

**The problem:**

I need to malloc a struct to populate a char *[64] array. This array gets corrupted when I free the struct. Specifically the first index. How should I deal with this?

```
int main(void) {
char *names[64];
uint32_t aCount = 0;
uint32_t count = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL,&count, NULL);
VkExtensionProperties *extension_names = malloc(sizeof(VkExtensionProperties) * count);
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL,&count,extension_names);

for(uint32_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    names[aCount++] = extension_names[i].extensionName;
}

printf("First extension available: %s\n",names[0]);

free(extension_names);

printf("First extension available: %s\n",names[0]);
return 0;}
```

**Here is the result:**

**Before free()**

First extension available: VK_KHR_device_group_creation

**After free()**

First extension available: ���yUU

Comment: You freed the strings, so not sure what you expect to happen. The second `printf()` will access freed memory.

Comment: You populate `names` with `char*` held internally in `extension_names[]`. After freeing the latter, don't expect the former to be valid, lest the library you're using intentionally foist a memory leak (which would be bad). Short version: If you want to keep the names, make copies, don't hold hot pointers to internal data you're eventually going to destroy. Unrelated, `aCount` seems somewhat pointless in this code.

Comment: Yes, aCount is pointless, but needed to change index thou.. could have used i.. This is only a snippet of used code to show what is going on. But yeah, I get your point. I have a array of pointers to non existent data after I free(extension_names)...

Comment: Check the value of `count`.   If it exceeds `64`, the loop before the first `printf()` has undefined behaviour - which, among other thins, can mess up the workings of the subsequent calls of `printf()` or of `free()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to make copies of the strings and solve the "use after free" problem you are having:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define UNUSED(x) \
    ((void)(x))

#define VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE 256

typedef struct VkExtensionProperties {
    char        extensionName[VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t    specVersion;
} VkExtensionProperties;

void vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(void *unused, 
        uint32_t *count, VkExtensionProperties *result) {
    UNUSED(unused);
    *count = 64;
    if (result) {
        for (int index = 0; index < *count; index++) {
            snprintf(result[index].extensionName, 
                    sizeof(result->extensionName), 
                    "extension%03d", 
                    index);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *names[64];
    uint32_t aCount = 0;
    uint32_t count = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL, &count, NULL);
    VkExtensionProperties *extension_names = malloc(sizeof(VkExtensionProperties) * count);
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL, &count, extension_names);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        names[aCount++] = strdup(extension_names[i].extensionName);
    }
    printf("First extension available: %s\n", names[0]);

    free(extension_names);

    printf("First extension available: %s\n", names[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
First extension available: extension000
First extension available: extension000
```

I don't have [Vulcan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) installed, so I simulated the behavior of the function you called.

**Helpful GCC Flags**

While I have your attention, don't forget to compile your code with `-Wall -Werror` to help you fix problems at compile time:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o program program.c
```

Comment: Also, compiling with address sanitizer is much more helpful to detect use after free or misuse of the heap in general: `-O0 -g -fsanitize=address -lasan -fno-omit-frame-pointer`

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `names[aCount++] = extension_names[i].extensionName;`

i.e. you are copying the `extension_names` in the array of pointers that is `names`.

You can only free `extension_names` after you are done with using `names`

Comment: Are you saying that my char array is an array of 64 pointers to char*? And when I free the struct, my char array is pointing to freed memory?

Comment: `names` is an array of 64 pointers to `char`.  After your first loop is done each element points to the first element of an array of `char`.  If you free the arrays those pointers point to you can't use the pointers to read from them anymore; they're gone.

Comment: aCount++ should make sure they point to subsequent elements. I guess in the original code, it was used to keep up on number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You freed the strings, so not sure what you expected to happen. The second `printf()` will access freed memory. If you want to keep the strings around longer, you should copy the string data, not just the pointers to that data. Also, you need to write safer code to avoid buffer overflows (you're not checking if you're writing past the end of `names`, for example.)

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count && aCount < 64; i++, aCount++) {
    // +1 for the '\0' terminator
    const size_t len = strlen(extension_names[i].extensionName) + 1;

    names[aCount] = malloc(len);
    memcpy(names[aCount], extension_names[i].extensionName, len);
}
```

Note that you now also have to `free()` each element in `names` when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thank you very many! I think my understanding of pointers is now better and also importance of managing memory better.